# Manifest merger failed : Referenced navigation file not found

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-architecture-components

I am trying to add a nested graph to my Navigation XML file. The main graph is in the app module and the nested graph is in a dependent library module. I am adding the subgraph with `<include>` tag. When I do it my build fails with manifest merger error. I have the main graph referenced in app's Manifest as `<nav-graph>` tag to support deep linking. I do search in the project but I can't find any references to my subgraph but in the include tag.

> Manifest merger failed : Referenced navigation file with
>   navigationXmlId = browse_nav_subgraph not found

Here is some code:

main graph:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/nav_graph" app:startDestination="@id/login">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/browse_nav_subgraph" />
//other fragments
</navigation>
```

browse_nav_subgraph:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:startDestination="@id/browseFragment"
        android:id="@+id/browse_subgraph">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/browseFragment" android:name="..."
              android:label="BrowseFragment"/>
</navigation>
```

app's manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest>
    <application>
        <activity>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_graph"/>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

browse module's manifest:

```
<manifest package="..."/>
```

The question is how to remove the error and have subgraph successfully added.

Comment: What version of the Android Gradle Plugin do you use (i.e., `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0-beta05'`)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

Comment: @ianhanniballake tried the beta plugin and 3.5 Android Studio beta release and the project built successfully. I was using the stable studio and plugin previously. So moving to beta solved it. thanks for help

Comment: I got this error in the latest stable release and in the latest beta release

Comment: Still happens with the last update of AS 4.0.2 and build.gradle com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2 @ianhanniballake any idea what to do? I am having the same scenario. i have multiple nav_graphs referencing a include of another nav_graph, and then boom today i created a new nav_graph and tried to include it, and i get this: Manifest merger failed : Illegal circular reference among navigation files when traversing navigation file references starting with navigationXmlId: nav_graph_parking

Comment: @Catluc - that sounds like [this completely separate issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/158406168), which is fixed for AGP 4.2.0-alpha04 or higher. As stated in that issue, including the same graph multiple times is not the right solution in any case, but upgrading will make it a warning, not an error.

Comment: @ianhanniballake thank you so much, i was able to fix this, by including the <includes> in parent nav_graph, and make a global action in sub nav_graph referencing to the ID on the included nav_graph, again thank you very much.

Comment: i'm still facing this issue on gradle plugin `4.1.2`. Anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140856013
The fix for this will be in 3.7 Canary 2 and 3.6 Beta 2

Answer (score -2):

This issue already fix in above gradle plugin 3.5. Just update you gradle plugin like below.

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
```

Comment: I'm seeing this issue in 3.6.2